# Terminating QWebSocketServer with connected sockets

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, sigint, qtwebsockets

I debug console multithreaded application written in C++/Qt 5.12.1. It is running on Linux Mint 18.3 x64.

This app has `SIGINT` handler, `QWebSocketServer` and `QWebSocket` table. It uses `close()` `QWebSocketServer` and call `abort()`/`deleteLater()` for items in `QWebSocket` table to handle the termination.

If the websocket client connects to this console app, then termination fails because of some running thread (I suppose it's internal `QWebSocket` thread).
Termination is successful if there were no connections.

How to fix it? So that the app gracefully exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To gracefully quit the socket server we can attempt:

The most important part is to allow the main thread event loop to run and wait on [QWebSocketServer::closed()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocketserver.html#closed) so that the slot calls [QCoreApplication::quit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit).

That can be done even with:

```
connect(webSocketServer, &QWebSocketServer::closed,
        QCoreApplication::instance(), &QCoreApplication::quit);
```

If we don't need more detailed reaction.

After connecting that signal before all, proceed with `pauseAccepting()` to prevent more connections.
Call `QWebSocketServer::close`.

*The below may not be needed if the above sufficient.* You need to try the above first, and only if still have problems then deal with existing and pending connections. From my experience the behavior was varying on platforms and with some unique websocket implementations in the server environment (which is likely just Qt for you).

As long as we have some array with `QWebSocket` instances, we can try to call `QWebSocket::abort()` on all of them to immediately release. This step seem to be described by the question author.

Try to iterate *pending* connections with [QWebSocketServer::nextPendingConnection()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocketserver.html#nextPendingConnection) and call `abort()` for them. Call `deleteLater`, if that works as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything. What do you mean by "graceful exit"? As soon as there's a request to terminate your application, you should terminate it immediately using `exit(0)` or a similar mechanism. That's what "graceful exit" should be.

Note: I got reformed. I used to think that graceful exits were a good thing. They are most usually a waste of CPU resources and usually indicate problems in the architecture of the application.

A good [rationale for why it should be so](https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/master/c%2B%2B/src/kj/main.h#L42) written in the `kj` framework (a part of capnproto).

Quoting Kenton Varda:

> `KJ_NORETURN(virtual void exit()) = 0;`
>
> Indicates program completion.  The program is considered successful unless `error()` was
>      called.  Typically this exits with `_Exit()`, meaning that the stack is not unwound, buffers
>      are not flushed, etc. -- it is the responsibility of the caller to flush any buffers that
>      matter.  However, an alternate context implementation e.g. for unit testing purposes could
>      choose to throw an exception instead.
>
> At first this approach may sound crazy.  Isn't it much better to shut down cleanly?  What if
>      you lose data?  However, it turns out that if you look at each common class of program, `_Exit()`
>      is almost always preferable.  Let's break it down:
>
> - Commands:  A typical program you might run from the command line is single-threaded and
>      exits quickly and deterministically.  Commands often use buffered I/O and need to flush
>      those buffers before exit.  However, most of the work performed by destructors is not
>      flushing buffers, but rather freeing up memory, placing objects into freelists, and closing
>      file descriptors.  All of this is irrelevant if the process is about to exit anyway, and
>      for a command that runs quickly, time wasted freeing heap space may make a real difference
>      in the overall runtime of a script.  Meanwhile, it is usually easy to determine exactly what
>      resources need to be flushed before exit, and easy to tell if they are not being flushed
>      (because the command fails to produce the expected output).  Therefore, it is reasonably
>      easy for commands to explicitly ensure all output is flushed before exiting, and it is
>      probably a good idea for them to do so anyway, because write failures should be detected
>      and handled.  For commands, a good strategy is to allocate any objects that require clean
>      destruction on the stack, and allow them to go out of scope before the command exits.
>      Meanwhile, any resources which do not need to be cleaned up should be allocated as members
>      of the command's main class, whose destructor normally will not be called.
> - Interactive apps:  Programs that interact with the user (whether they be graphical apps
>      with windows or console-based apps like emacs) generally exit only when the user asks them
>      to.  Such applications may store large data structures in memory which need to be synced
>      to disk, such as documents or user preferences.  However, relying on stack unwind or global
>      destructors as the mechanism for ensuring such syncing occurs is probably wrong.  First of
>      all, it's 2013, and applications ought to be actively syncing changes to non-volatile
>      storage the moment those changes are made.  Applications can crash at any time and a crash
>      should never lose data that is more than half a second old.  Meanwhile, if a user actually
>      does try to close an application while unsaved changes exist, the application UI should
>      prompt the user to decide what to do.  Such a UI mechanism is obviously too high level to
>      be implemented via destructors, so KJ's use of `_Exit()` shouldn't make a difference here.
> - Servers:  A good server is fault-tolerant, prepared for the possibility that at any time
>      it could crash, the OS could decide to kill it off, or the machine it is running on could
>      just die.  So, using _Exit() should be no problem.  In fact, servers generally never even
>      call exit anyway; they are killed externally.
> - Batch jobs:  A long-running batch job is something between a command and a server.  It
>      probably knows exactly what needs to be flushed before exiting, and it probably should be
>      fault-tolerant.

Comment: With our server that serves nodes of proprietary equipment we should better direct the equipment to be properly "disengaged" while exiting the server process. Of course the issue stems from incapable drivers. But that is just an example. P.S. The term "graceful" is on me as I read my countryman wording which I translated to better English

Comment: How do you handle failures? A server process may fail hard. The server hardware may die. Someone may wish, in the future to have to servers running behind a failover front-end. In all of those cases, the current server will "die" and another has to take over from scratch. The equipment should fail-safe when the server process dies. Is that not the case?

Comment: Of course that part is neither bullet proof nor I designed it. Periodically, the client device detects whether or not a link with the server is "still alive" so that it resets if not. Simple connection interruption not worth it to go down right away, though.

Comment: There is a significant difference between "this server has mysteriously failed" and "this server was intentionally shut down"